# How to prove $W_t-tW_1$ is Markov?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, markov-process, brownian-bridge

For a Brownian motion $W_t$, how do we prove the bridge process $W_t-tW_1$ is Markov? Essentially, we need to prove for $s< t$,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(W_t-tW_1\in x\mid \mathcal{F}_s)=\mathbb{P}(W_t-tW_1\in x\mid W_s)
\end{align}

I understand I need to use $W_t-W_s$ being independent of $\mathcal{F}_s$, but how to use that for proving the above statement?

Comment: This follows because $X_t:=W_t-tW_1$, like $W_t$,  is a Gaussian process, whose covariance $E[X_sX_s]=s(1-t)$ ($0\leq s\leq t\leq 1$) factors into a function of $s$ and a function of $t$. You may need to review how to compute conditional distributions for a Gaussian process.

Answer (score 1):

The Brownian bridge is a Markov process because it is an Itô process. In particular, we may use Itô's formula to check that $Y_t = W_t - tW_1$ satisfies the following SDE: $$dY_t = - \frac{Y_t}{1-t}dt + dB_t$$

Comment: I get from Ito's formula - $dY_t=dW_t-W_1+0.5dt$, how to get to your equation from there?